# How can I de-reference an object in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, object, reference

I have a buffer that cycles between two indices and I want to write out the object at the current index in a task and allow the rest of the program to continue processing things. I have attempted to simplify the process while maintaining all the pertinent parts.

```
    object[] buffer = new object[2]
    int currentIndex = 0

    while(true){
        buffer[currentIndex].field1 = newdatahere //data grabbed by sensor bundle
        buffer[currentIndex].field2 = newdatahere //data grabbed by camera bundle
        buffer[currentIndex].field3 = newdatahere //data grabbed from system snapshot

        task.factory.starnew(()=>{
            writeOutObject(buffer[currentIndex])
        }

        buffer[currentIndex] = new object();

        currentIndex = 1 - currentIndex //cycle between the 0 and 1 indices
    }

    void writeOutObject(Object obj){
        //do file IO here
        //write out field1, field2, field3
    }
```

The problem is that by assigning the buffer item to a new object I am killing the writeOutObject method because the obj no longer exists by the time the task runs. I want to be able to keep the old object until it is written out and have the buffer point to a new object.

What I want to do:

```
    object obj1 = new object();
    obj1.field1 = data1;
    obj1.field2 = data2;
    obj1.field3 = data3;

    obj2 = obj1;
    //de-reference obj1 from the object that it was pointed to and associate it to a new object

    // i want this to write out data1,data2,data3 but instead it is 
    // writing out data4,data5,data6 or some mixture because it has 
    // been overwritten halfway through the file IO
    task.factory.startnew(()=>{ write out obj2 } 

    obj1.field1 = data4;
    obj1.field2 = data5;
    obj1.field3 = data6;
```

Maybe something like:

```
    obj1 = new object()

    obj2* = &obj1
    obj1* = &new object
```

I need to break the reference of obj1 back to obj2 once it has been assigned. Simply doing this won't work:

```
    obj1 = new object()
    obj2 = obj1
    obj1 = null // or new object()
```

As requested, "The Real Code"

```
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public void StartMachine()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                _isFirstData = true;
                _expiredFlag = false;
                Plc.StartPLC();
                Plc.Start();

                while (true)
                {
                    if (!_paused && !Plc.IsInputStackEmpty() && !Plc.IsOutputSlideOpen())
                    {

                        CameraFront.SnapAquire();

                        // If this is the first data set the wait handles
                        if (!_isFirstData)
                        {
                            CameraBack.SnapAquire();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _imageBackRecieved.Set();
                            _databaseInfoRecieved.Set();
                            //_isFirstCard = false;
                        }

                        // Wait for 3 things! Image Front, Image Back, Database
                        bool gotEvents = WaitHandle.WaitAll(_waitHandles, TIMEOUT);
                        if (gotEvents)
                        {
                            if (!_isFirstData)
                            {
                                if (Buffer[1 - NextDataOutIndex].IsDataComplete())
                                {
                                    if (Buffer[1 - NextDataOutIndex].EvaluateData()) 
                                    {
                                        OnPassFailNotification()
                                        Plc.Pass();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        OnPassFailNotification()
                                        Plc.Fail();
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    OnPassFailNotification()
                                    Plc.Fail();
                                    Common.Logging
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                _isFirstData = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           Common.Logging("WARNING: Wait handle timed out"
                            Plc.Fail();
                        }

                        Data temp = Buffer[1 - NextDataOutIndex];
                        Task.Factory.Startnew(()=>{
                            Data.WriteData(temp);
                        }
                        Buffer[1 - NextDataOutIndex] = new Data(); 

                        // Swap card buffers - alternate between 1 and 0
                        NextdataOutIndex = 1 - NextDataOutIndex;

                        // Do this
                        Plc.WheelAdvance();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }
            }, cts.Token);                
    }


    public static void WriteData(Data data)
    {
        if(WRITE_BATCH_FILES)
        try
        {
            if (data.ImageFront != null)
            {
                string filenameforfront = "blahlbah-front.tiff";
                OperatorSet.WriteImage(data.ImageFront, "tiff", 0, filenameforfront);
            }
            if (data.ImageBack != null)
            {
                string filenameforback = "blahblah-back.tiff";
                HOperatorSet.WriteImage(data.ImageBack, "tiff", 0, filenameforback);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Common.Logging.
            //throw ex;
        }

        //TODO: Write out data in xml
        //TODO: Write out metrics
    }
```

Comment: "The problem is that by assigning the buffer item to a new object I am killing the writeOutObject method because the obj no longer exists by the time the task runs" - no, that shouldn't be happening. I strongly suspect you're misdiagnosing the problem. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help.

Comment: btw; I see no pointers there.

Comment: Are you every actually doing something with a group these objects? If not, If all you are ever doing is writing them to a file, why buffer them like that at all?

Comment: @JonSkeet Unfortunately the program is a bit too complex to transcribe here. The fields are actually populated in an arbitrary order from several event handlers and the 0 and 1 indexed objects are being populated simultaneously. It is only when the object is completely filled out that it is written out. And to clarify, it's not that the object doesn't exist, it has typically just be overwritten with new data as the buffer continues to cycle. Will try to update code with a clearer picture.

Comment: I didn't ask for your actual code - I asked for a short but complete program which demonstrated the problem. You can start off with a copy of your current code and cut bits out of it until all you've got left is a minimal example. You may very well find that in the process of doing so, you discover the problem.

Comment: This line of code confuses me:  `buffer(currentIndex).field1`.  If `buffer` is an array, that line should generate a compile time error since parenthesis are not used to access arrays in c#

Comment: Was the call to `TaskFactory.StartNew` in the question from the start? I completely missed it earlier on...

Comment: @ChrisDunaway will edit that, it was a typo.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes the taskfactory was in there from the very beggining.

Comment: Okay, well apologies for missing it. Short but complete code - and at the least *real* code rather than pseudo-code with all the names incorrect etc - is still a good idea :)

Comment: @JonSkeet No worries. I have also posted the trimmed down real code.

Comment: I would venture to suggest you could trim it a lot further - and make it more complete. I suspect this could be reproduced in about 20 lines of code... there's not a lot of point now, but it's a good skill to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just before you task.factory.StartNew do the following

```
while(...)
{
   ... bunch of other code
   buildTask(buffer[currentIndex]);
   buffer[currentIndex] = new object();
   ... bunch of other code
}

// Within this method, all references to detachedBuffer object will remain pointing to the same
// memory location no matter whether the variable passed in is reassigned.
public void buildTask(object detachedBuffer)
{
    task.factory.starnew(()=>{
        writeOutObject(detachedBuffer);
    };

}
```

Comment: This is definitely better than my suggestion - too much time working in embedded C does bad things to one's mind!

Comment: Unfortunately this approach has the same problem. As soon as buffer[currentIndex] = new object(); executes it is still pointed to the same data as detachedBuffer.

Comment: This will happen if detachedBuffer is re-initialized before the task can be started; which is possible in such a small loop. To make this work all the time you should put the task initialization in its own method, and pass the detachedBuffer object to that methods as a parameter. This will ensure that the detachedBuffer semantic within the task delegate is always the same one that was passed into the method when it was executed. I've modded my answer accordingly.

Comment: I believe this has fixed the problem. The method call blocks until the task is completely started with its own reference to the detached buffer, then the method returns and the rest of the loop execution can continue. Will update if I see anything else peculiar.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for Semaphores!
Semaphores are a form of inter-thread communication that are ideal for this situation as they allow one thread to lock the semaphore but another to release it again. In the code sample below, the `sem.WaitOne()` line will wait until the `sem.Release()` method has been called. This blocks your main thread for just long enough that your task gets hold of the data it needs.

```
object[] buffer = new object[2]
int currentIndex = 0

while(true){
    buffer(currentIndex).field1 = newdatahere //data grabbed by sensor bundle
    buffer(currentIndex).field2 = newdatahere //data grabbed by camera bundle
    buffer(currentIndex).field3 = newdatahere //data grabbed from system snapshot

    Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1,1);  //Initialise the semaphore so that it is checked out

    task.factory.starnew(()=>{
        object item = buffer[currentIndex]; //Create local reference to the data item
        sem.Release(); //Check-in the semaphore (let the WaitOne method return)
        writeOutObject(item)
    }

    sem.WaitOne(); //Block until the semaphore has returned

    buffer[currentIndex] = new object();

    currentIndex = 1 - currentIndex //cycle between the 0 and 1 indices
}

void writeOutObject(Object obj){
    //do file IO here
    //write out field1, field2, field3
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is needed? I see no reason to leap for locking at all. I believe the OP has misdiagnosed the issue, but I can't see how what you're suggesting would help.

Comment: This just negates the point of using the async block. It'll work but the OP may as well just call writeOutObject in-line.

Comment: @JonSkeet - The way I read it, unless the writeOutObject(buffer[currentIndex]) executes before the buffer[currentIndex] = new object(); (which is not guaranteed because its a task) then the OP would indeed see his buffer[currentIndex] beign set to new Object BEFORE it could get written to disk.

Comment: @PhillipH: But if `writeOutObject` uses the parameter it has been passed, `buffer` is completely irrelevant to it. It doesn't matter that the element in `buffer` no longer has the same value - the `writeOutObject` method already has a reference to the object it's trying to write. The OP's claim that the object is "killed" makes no sense with the code they've posted.

Comment: The OP seems to have a race condition. They kick off a new thread (TaskFactory.StartNew) which requires a peice of data but then instantly change the data. By the time `writeOutObject(buffer[currentIndex])` is executed on the ThreadPool, `buffer[currentIndex] = new object();` may have already been actioned.

Comment: @PhillipH assuming that writeOutObject is a time-consuming action, this code means that the main thread doesn't have to wait until writeOutObject completes, but only until the TaskScheduler gets round to this task +  a few ns

Comment: Aha - apologies, I'm with it now. I hadn't seen the TaskFactory.StartNew call. There's still a simpler approach, but at least I understand now...

Comment: @JonSkeet - the evaluation of the parameter to writeObject is non-deterministic - it may well not get called until the array reassignment occurs, only then will the internal delegate in the task get evaluated. Its a delayed evaluation becasue its a task.

Comment: @PhillipH: As I say, I'd missed the "starting a new task" part (assuming that was in the very first version of the question; it's possible it changed after I saw it but within the first 5 minutes). At that point it makes complete sense, and your answer is the way forward.

Comment: The problem isn't really a real 'race condition' I basically want to accomplish the work of a deep copy but with a simple reference swap or pointer swap. The race is only a problem because I am not copying the object to a new object something

Comment: @JonSkeet - I think we had our very own "Race Condition" on the Add Comment button, apologies.